# sql - unpivot multiple column

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery

I am new to sql and I'm looking for some help for my project, so basically I have the below data set and I would like to unpivot these columns, currently I am using google big query. Thank you for your help

| Account Name | License_m1 | License_m2 | License_m3 | rev_m1 | rev_m2 | rev_m3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 10 | 14 | 12 | 50 | 60 | 45 |
| Samsung | 0 | 21 | 21 | 0 | 25 | 25 |

The results I would like to get

| Account Name | Month | License | Rev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | License_m1 | 10 | 50 |
| Apple | License_m2 | 14 | 60 |
| Apple | License_m3 | 12 | 45 |
| Samsung | License_m1 | 0 | 0 |
| Samsung | License_m2 | 21 | 25 |
| Samsung | License_m3 | 21 | 25 |

I've tried with this query but unsure this is the right logic to do it.

select
Account_Name
Date
License
from my table
unpivot
(License
for Date in (License_m1,License_m2,License_m3))

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and the expected result as properly formatted text, i.e. no images no links. Also show us your current query attempt. And add a tag for the dbms you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Use below approach (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
select account_name, regexp_extract(month, r'(m\d+)') as month, licence, rev
from your_table
unpivot ((licence, rev) for month in ((License_m1, rev_m1), (License_m2, rev_m2), (License_m3, rev_m3)))
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Hi Mikhail!

Hope you are well!

Thanks for your help I've tried this query in GCP it seems to be working but the license and the month column gives me 'null' values. I found that the license column type is float and the revenue is string, I assume thats the reason why it's not showing values , can you advise please?

Comment: i answered your question as it is and based on provided data sample! looks like your data in reality is different from what you presented, so you might want to ask new question!!